# How to reload collection in EF Core 2.x?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I know there is a `Load` method.

```cs
_dbContext.Entry(blog).Collection(b => b.Posts).Load()
```

But I'm try to handle concurrency conflicts, I've been add a `post` into `blog.Posts`. if call `Load`, it do not clear the `blog.Posts`, just append the existing `Posts` to it.

I had try:

```cs
blog.Posts = null;
_dbContext.Entry(blog).Collection(b => b.Posts).Load()
```

But `blog.Posts` become a empty collection (Zero Count).

So I want a `Reload`.

Comment: It seems your basic issue is trying to use a `DbContext` in a multi-threaded manner. Each thread should have it's own instance of `DbContext` as [outlined in the "Avoiding DbContext threading issues" section of the EF documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext).

Comment: @SixtoSaez No, it's not multithead, I ensure. DbContext is from DI. I just use Class.Method to describe which class's instance and call which method. I change DbContext to _dbContext for clarifying this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately although `EntityEntry` has `Reload` method, there is no such method for `ReferenceEntry` and `CollectionEntry` (or in general, for `NavigationEntry` which the base of the previous two). And `Reload` methods refreshes just the primitive properties, so it can't be used to refresh the navigation properties.

Fortunately it's not that hard to create a custom one. It needs to detach (or reload?) all the current collection items, set `IsLoaded` to `false` and `CurrentValue` to `null` before calling `Load`.

Something  like this (put it in a static class of your choice and add the necessary `using`s):

```
public static void Reload(this CollectionEntry source)
{
    if (source.CurrentValue != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in source.CurrentValue)
            source.EntityEntry.Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
        source.CurrentValue = null;
    }
    source.IsLoaded = false;
    source.Load();
}
```

so you can use the desired

```
_dbContext.Entry(blog).Collection(b => b.Posts).Reload();
```

Comment: Is the `Detached` assign necessary ? If I only set the `source.CurrentValue = null;` then set `source.IsLoaded = false;` and `source.Load();`, is it safe ?

Comment: Nope. My  test shows all these are necessary. W/o detaching the items you'll get the cached items instead of fresh items from database  plus added items but not deleted items.

Comment: @IvanStoev This did not work for me. Please have a look here if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65723105/3850405

Comment: I tested this solution, it works but be careful: If some elements of the reloaded collection are in lists of some other object, they will still be in those list in "Detached" state and the latest version will be added too. So you would have twice the same element, one being "Detached".

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to reload a reference is reload the entity of the reference itself. But in case reference is loaded and its entity is null, you can simply set IsLoaded property to false and then execute ReferenceEntry.Load().

So, based on [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) code, this is my code for ReferenceEntry

```
public static void Reload(this ReferenceEntry source)
      {
         if (source.CurrentValue != null)
         {
            var entry = source.EntityEntry.Context.Entry(source.CurrentValue);
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
            {
               entry.Reload();
               return;
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
               source.CurrentValue = null;
            }
            else
            {
               return;
            }
         }
         source.IsLoaded = false;
         source.Load();
      }
```

Note that I take into account the State property, since when Detached, Reload() throws an error. Also, I only want to reload if it's Unchanged. But that's your decision.